# What is wrong with print object po, Objective - C Xcode's LLDB debugger?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to debug these lines of codes:

```
#pragma mark - TableView Delegates
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    NSLog(@"%i", self.sectionList.count)
    return self.sectionList.count;   
}
```

But when i write po these to see the value, after little pause nothing happens.. Any idea and how should i approach to this situation ?

```
(lldb) po self.sectionList.count
(lldb) p self.sectionList.count
```

Comment: Is it possible that you're filtering the log output, i.e., you've entered some text in the filter field at the bottom of the log view.

Comment: thank you for your point but my filter is clear.  Even if it was written some text next to green (lldb)  area it would be always visible. You can try

Comment: Not a lldb user but I see your NSLog ... what does that log and why not log self.sectionList there as well to inspect?

Comment: @skaak i deleted the NSLog but it react same,  i can`t use lldb po someobject

Comment: I'm just fishing can't really help with this one but is it just this object or others too? (e.g. self here)

Comment: all of them is same, but when i try for another project, it is working.

Comment: Debug symbols not maybe off for this project?

Comment: hmm how can i check that and put it active for this project ?

Comment: @skaak i think problem could be about compiled time as the size of the project is big which includes lots storyboards. What is your opinion ?

Comment: @zeytin check in the build settings if anything is set to *strip debug symbols* or *strip linked product* and also check if your scheme uses the debug configuration in this project.

Comment: Wish I could help more but I don't really use lldb ...

Comment: it is ok. you mostly prefer NSLog ?

Comment: Yes I use that a lot and also #define statements - old C tricks. Works really nice and flexible and keeps debug and prod code separate. You like lldb?

Comment: All google tells me is that you should check that you do not use release but debug, check your filters and reboot and use Xcode 12 - seems Xcode 11 had this problem sometimes.