# Xcode lldb po command doesn't output info

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, lldb

For some reason `lldb` stopped outputting any information when running `p` or `po` commands.

As suggested in other topic I have tried the following without any success:

- Cleaning the project
- `Optimization Level` project setting set to `none`
- `Debug Information Format` set to `DWARF with dSYM File`

I am running `Xcode 12.2` on `MacOS BigSur 11.0.1` but I that happens prior updating both XCode and the OS.

[image]

Comment: good one. i once asked this question but could not find an exact answer. If you wish you can check out: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64575909/14531220

Comment: @zeytin thanks for your answer. I have read the tread in your question too, unfortunatly non of it worked :(

Comment: Any progress, still wonder the solution :) ?

Comment: Not really. For now we ignore the problem and the good old "cave-man" debugging with print statements which is often inconvenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue !

The issue was that we had an import in `PROJECT_NAME-Bridging-Header.h` which was making `Foundation` and `UIKit` frameworks globally available across the project. As soon as we removed that import the debugging was back to normal.

It it really-project specific issue. The answer might not help you if you are dealing with different kind of setup in your project.

Answer (score 0):

For my case the problem was about compiled time as the size of the project was big which includes lots storyboards. That was my lldb po was stuck for Xcode 11.6.

Good luck

Comment: My project has no storyboards but code layout, I guess storyboards here wouldn't not be problem.